# How to create a link that uses a route?

Tags: 8, routes

I am trying to add a link to a taxonomy landing page, like this

```
$breadcrumbs->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($term_name,"/taxonomy/term/$tid"));
```

but I get the following error : `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "/taxonomy/term/2041" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 187 of C:\drupaldevsites\pup-dev\docroot\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider.php).`

Comment: The argument has to be a route name, not a path.

Comment: see also https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248224/taxonomy-term-route-name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument has to be a route name.

Try:

```
$breadcrumbs->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($term_name, "entity.taxonomy_term.canonical", ["taxonomy_term" => $tid]));
```

[See the docs for this method](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Link.php/function/Link%3A%3AcreateFromRoute/8.2.x).

Answer (score 0):

Get the route name using :

```
dump(\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName());
```

then use that route name :

```
$myBreadcrumbs [] = Link::createFromRoute('News Centre', 'ROUTE_NAME');
```