# Taxonomy term route name?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, routes, breadcrumbs

I am trying to make a custom taxonomy breadcrumbs based the code from this question:
[Drupal 8 How to do a custom taxonomy breadcrumb?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230722/drupal-8-how-to-do-a-custom-taxonomy-breadcrumb)

This line adds a new breadcrumb for the home page:

```
$breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute(t('Home'), 'front'));
```

PS: I removed parenthesis from front to display line here.

I want to add another breadcrumb with the text of the name of a taxonomy term and the URL of the same term:

```
$breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute(t($term->getName()), $url));
```

I cannot figure out how to replace "front" with the route name of the `$term` object.

Comment: try using like 
$breadcrumb->addLink(\Drupal\Core\Link::fromTextAndUrl(t($term->getName()), $url)));

Comment: fromTextAndUrl Function takes url object as an input, how can i get the url object of a certain term ?

Comment: Use this \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUserInput("YOUR LINK GOES HERE")

Comment: see also https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233530/how-to-create-a-link-that-uses-a-route

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since taxonomy terms are entities, you can simply do this:

```
$link = $term->toLink();
$breadcrumb->addLink($link);
```

As a side-note, the route name for taxonomy terms is "entity.taxonomy_term.canonical".